# How to create an virtual working environment?

Tags: python

I wish to use Django to create a Web app, but first I need to create an virtual environment.

Since I have a Windows system, I have used Win+R and cmd to open the teriminal, then the system shows C:\Users\HP>, I tried to create a datalog named learning_log and use terminal to switch to this datalog, so I typed in learning_log$ python -m venv 11_env, but the system shows 'learning_log$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

May I know how to create a datalog and how to create an virtual working environment?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me why you need a 'datalog' to create a Django web app, so I'll just help out with the VENV side of things.

[To create a virtual environment in Python:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

A full guide to getting started with a virtual environment in Django can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/windows/).

Open the current directory in a terminal. The easiest way to do this is probably open command prompt like you did.

`Win Key + R` -> `cmd`

Then copy the directory to your current folder from the top of File Explorer e.g. `C:\Users\user_name\Documents\test_venv`

Then paste this into the terminal like so

```
python -m venv "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\test_venv"
```

This will create a virtual environment at that directory. Now navigate to that directory using terminal `cd "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\test_venv"` and you can perform your next actions.

It's easiest to do this if you have an IDE and can just set it up to load a terminal in your current directory. Then you don't need to navigate to it and can just create the virtual environment at the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install **virtualenv** library:

- `pip3 install virtualenv`

After installing virtualenv, now create virtual environment directory with any name:

- `virtualenv myvenv`

Now you can see, myvenv folder. now you can activate the virtual environment using that folder location:

- `.\myvenv\Scripts\activate.bat`

Now you can see the virtual environment activated and you can see **(myvenv)** on your command prompt.